# using JQuery.browser to choose CSS based on layout engine

Tags: jquery, css, layout, cross-browser, browser-detection

I don't see why this doesn't work. I assume that for some really lame reason an if statement might not be able to validate a string of text but that would make me very angry at who's writing these scripting languages.

```
//I don't want to know the browser. I want to know the layout engine the user is using.
if($.layout.name == "webkit"){$("#debug").html("your browser uses webkit");}

//I eventually want to do this
if($.layout.name == "webkit"){
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/webkit-name-v006.css" type="text/css" media="screen">');
}
```

I looked all over for documentation on how to use the jquery.browser plugin but they only give info for detecting the specific browser name they do not give examples for checking for layout engine.

```
//this is the closest working example I found online
$.browser.safari = /safari/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); if ($.browser.safari) { 
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.tld/css/safari.css" type="text/css" media="screen">'); }
```

I need to write a script that chooses the CSS file based on browser layout, not version.

I don't wanna hear any hype about feature detection. I have been there and seen it's error.
Just wanna make this work.

Thanks.

Comment: $.browser.safari is deprecated as of jQuery 1.4.

Comment: Nope. It is good for working distinguishing between different user Agents once you've negotiated what layout engine they are using but other than that we will never see it catch on because it has many serious flaws. In theory though it is actually a good idea.

Comment: What serious flaws?  Browser detection is flawed.

Comment: the biggest problem with feature detection is when there is a feature you want to detect that no one has figured out how to detect yet you have to wait for jquery or someone to figure out out.  AS OF NOW there are tons of things that FEATURE DETECTION is necessary for and yet can not detect. As new browsers are released and CSS and HTML are upgraded you will see more features that you want to use feature detection for and yet CANT because there is simply no way to detect for it. ////NOW //// I see tons of people returning to browser detection because feature detection is only a utopia.

Comment: this is why we have people coming out with great stuff like this. [http://jreject.turnwheel.com/] Best Practice is to make users who do not upgrade feel bad and have to use a minimized version of your site until they upgrade their browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//FOUND THE ANSWER
I was putting the code in an if statement string and for got to say "else if"

Here is the working code

```
//WEBKIT    SAFARI CHROME     CSS
if($.layout.name == 'webkit'){$("#debug").html("your browser uses webkit");}
//GECKO     FIREFOX MOZILLA   CSS
else if($.layout.name == 'gecko'){$("#debug").html("your browser uses gecko");}
//TRIDENT   IE                CSS
else if($.layout.name == "trident"){$("#debug").html("your browser uses trident");}
//PRESTO    OPERAH            CSS
else if($.layout.name == "presto"){$("#debug").html("your browser uses presto");}
//KNOW ONE KNOWS
else{$("#debug").html("your browser is unrecognized");}
//IOS       IPHONE            CSS
//ANDROID   GALAXY            CSS
```

Comment: Just an FYI, Trident(msie) versions vary greatly from version to version. You probably can't write a single css layout that will work on all versions of the Trident engine.

Comment: For that I'm planning to use feature detection 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($.browser.webkit){
        $("head").append(
            $("<link />").attr({
                rel:  "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "file.css"
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you append something and then turn around and select it again?  You should apply the attributes first, and then append.

Comment: You could also use `$.layout.name == 'webkit'`.

Comment: Of course, my point was mainly to avoid using `document.write`.

Comment: You don't have to use `document.write` to apply attributes before appending the node.

Comment: There, I optimized it for you.

Comment: um... first off I am using the jquery.browser.js plugin because jquery is only deprecating it in their main library and have moved it to plugin form which is fine by me.   //////////NEXT////// none of the suggestions you gave have worked. In fact one of the suggestions was exactly as I had written it /$.layout.name == 'webkit'/ is exactly what I used originally.

Comment: by the way using [append] to the head tag was a great idea. And thanks for your guys input.